# Issues to debug my code in my Xcode Framework

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, debugging, lldb

I have one workspace, where I have 2 projects:

1. main app project with just 1 target of the main app
2. Framework project with just 1 framework target

**I import Framework into main app.**

Then I set a breakpoint in the Framework's file, I start the main app, I see that code execution stopped at this breakpoint

[image]

But when I try printing a variable, it says

```
error: Couldn't IRGen expression, no additional error
```

I assume that smth is wrong in the settings of one of the projects. May be I need to somehow turn off binary compilation for my framework?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing carthage folder and running

```
carthage bootstrap --platform ios --cache-builds --no-use-binaries --new-resolver
```

made it to work.

Comment: Swift uses a serialization of it's internal state as the debug information format for type information.  That means that all your swift code with debug  information has to be built with the same swift compiler (the one that ships alongside the lldb you are using to debug.)  That's why you have to do `--no-use-binaries`.